# image needs to be in the same position

Tags: html, image

i am tryin to place this globe image in the exact position, but when the page is not in full screen, for some reason, the globe image disappears. What changes should i make to make sure that when the screen is not in full screen, the image stays in the same position?

```
div.image {
   content:url(../images/logonew.png);

   position: absolute;
   left: 11.4%;
   top:1%;
   width: 77px;
   height: 69px;
   z-index: -1;
   repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Give demo link OR make jsfiddle

Comment: `repeat` is not a valid style for css, im assuming you mean `background-repeat`. and im also assuming you mean `background-image` not `content`?

Comment: @haxxxton yes that is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your z-index:-1 might be part of the problem, most things on a web page default to z-index:0, and could cover over an image with a z-index:-1.

Anyway, the thing I've personally found that works well for me is something like this:

```
 <div style="position:relative">    <!--relative to preceding stuff on web page -->
 <img style="position:absolute" />  <!--absolute with respect to inside the <div> block -->
 <img style="position:absolute" />  <!--obviously you need to specify more style data than shown here! -->
 <!--as many more images as you like, organized to precise locations inside the <div> block-->
 <!--other elements can also be precisely positioned in the <div> block; things like <p> and <span>
     and <input> and <select> and <table> tags can have style data -->
 </div>
 <br />
 <br />
 <!-- use as many line-breaks as needed to reserve enough page-space for the stuff in the <div> block -->
 <br />
 <br />
 <!-- the rest of the web page now begins -->
```